# Extract key:value, key2:value2 strings out of JSON

Tags: python, json, text

When I use this code with Sanic

```py
@app.route('/orders', methods=["GET", "OPTIONS"])
async def get_orders(request):
    conn = psycopg2.connect(user='postgres', password='baldauren15', database='pyDB', host='127.0.0.1', port=5432)
    cursor = conn.cursor()
    if request.method == "GET":
        cursor.execute('SELECT * from orders_view')
        record = cursor.fetchall()
        ecdj = json.dumps(record, default=str)
        return response.html(ecdj)
    else:
        return response.json({"status": "not found"})
```

in output we have:

```
[[7, "baby", "Americano", "Not ready", "2023-01-08 07:05:06"], [5, "nurtyleu", "Capucino", "Ready", "2023-01-08 07:05:06"]]
```

My question is how can I do like this:

```
id:7, name:baby, order:Americano, status:Not ready, time:2023-01-08 07:05:06
```

and next order in under

```
id:5, name:Nurtyleu, order:Americano, status:Not ready, time:2023-01-08 07:05:06
```

I would like it without brackets.

I tried to change JSON to HTML or text and I use `class orders(object):` instead of an array `orders=[]`
but I always get output with brackets or JSON.

Comment: Do you want a single string with comma-separated "key:value" pairs, or a list of `key:value` pairs? Simply build that instead of returning JSON (then curse yourself for not using proper data structures in your internal logic).

Comment: yep, i need list of key:value, can you help how i can do that

Comment: `[f"{key}:{value}" for key, value in ... something]`

Comment: that is i need use cycle for upload key and value?

Comment: You need to loop over the values in order to build a list of them, yes. It's not clear where you would get the keywords from; perhaps your secret SQL already contains this information, or you could add a second query to get the field names. It would perhaps be more scalable to loop over the cursor than to fetch all the results in one go.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you want a list-of-dicts, you'll need to read the result column names from [`cursor.description`](https://www.psycopg.org/docs/cursor.html#cursor.description) and form `records` with that:

```
cursor.execute('SELECT * from orders_view')
columns = [desc[0] for desc in cursor.description]
records = [dict(zip(columns, row)) for row in cursor.fetchall()]
return response.html(json.dumps(records, default=str))
```

Comment: Yep its work must better Thank you